# Why can't other user remove /dev/shm/xxx even with o+rw permissions?

Tags: linux

I have python scripts that creates shared semaphore `/dev/shm/sem.serialize_ld` with permissions

```
$ ll /dev/shm/sem.serialize_ld                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
-rw-rw-rw- 1 buildbot buildbot 32 mar 27 08:36 /dev/shm/sem.serialize_ld
```

In practice it is always created by user buildbot, but it is not design assumption. 
Sometimes problem happens - script is killed by `SIGKILL` and doesn't release semaphore. New invocations deadlock on start. To manually fix this situation I want to remove the file and start over. However only buildbot and root users can do this.

Why can't different user remove this file?

```
$ rm /dev/shm/sem.serialize_ld                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
rm: cannot remove '/dev/shm/sem.serialize_ld': Operation not permitted
```

System is Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Script code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

import posix_ipc                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
import subprocess                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
import sys                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
import signal                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

SEM_NAME = '/serialize_ld'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
MAX_CONCURRENT = 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
PROGRAM = '/usr/bin/ld'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            


def main():                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    import os                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    os.umask(0)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    sem = posix_ipc.Semaphore(SEM_NAME, posix_ipc.O_CREAT, mode=0o666, initial_value=MAX_CONCURRENT)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    sem.acquire()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

    def release_semaphore(signum, frame):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        print("exiting due to signal " + str(signum))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        sem.release()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        sem.close()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        sys.exit(1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM | signal.SIGINT, release_semaphore)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

    try:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        subprocess.call([PROGRAM, *sys.argv[1:]])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    finally:
        sem.release()
        sem.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: To remove a file you need write permissions in the directory where the file resides, not for the file itself. check the permissions of `/dev/shm/`.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider It is even more liberal (by default): `$ ll /dev/shm -d
drwxrwxrwt 2 root root 60 mar 27 08:36 /dev/shm/`

Comment: No, it isn't. See [this question about the `t` bit in the permissions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/432699/what-is-the-t-letter-in-the-output-of-ls-ld-tmp).

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Ok, great. Can you write it as answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your directory `/dev/shm/` has the sticky bit `t` set:

```
$ ll /dev/shm -d 
drwxrwxrwt 2 root root 60 mar 27 08:36 /dev/shm/
```

Quote from [this answer on askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/432699/what-is-the-t-letter-in-the-output-of-ls-ld-tmp/432703#432703):

> **So what is the sticky bit?**
>
> A sticky bit is a permission bit that is set on a directory that allows only the owner of the file within that directory, the owner of the directory or the root user to delete or rename the file. No other user has the needed privileges to delete the file created by some other user.
>
> This is a security measure to avoid deletion of critical folders and their content (sub-directories and files), though other users have full permissions.

See [the answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/432699/what-is-the-t-letter-in-the-output-of-ls-ld-tmp/432703#432703) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

`/dev/shm` directory has "sticky bit" set (trailing 't') - see `man chmod` for details/consequences.

Suggested fix: create subdirectory in `/dev/shm` without sticky bit set and use it for your semaphore files.

---

`man chmod`

> The  letters  rwxXst  select  file  mode  bits  […] restricted  deletion  flag  or  sticky bit (t).
>   […]
>   **RESTRICTED DELETION FLAG OR STICKY BIT**
>   The  restricted  deletion  flag or sticky bit is a single bit, whose interpretation depends on the file type.  For directories, it prevents unprivileged users from removing or renaming a file in the directory unless they own the file or the directory;  this  is  called  the  restricted  deletion  flag for the directory, and is commonly found on world-writable directories like /tmp. […]